# Can you please help identify this light-green and gold set?

Tags: set-identification

Can you guys please help me identify this set, looks like some Ninjago set, but that is as far as I can get.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

[image]

*[Set #70612 Green Ninja Mech Dragon.](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=70612-1)*

The color, sand green, doesn't come up often in sets.  Cross search a very unique piece in this off color, to get a short list of potential hits, then zone in.